# Docker-compose config front-end with back-end's IP from host's perspective

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose

I would like to create a simple docker-compose setup. I have a static front-end implemented in JS served by nginx - this is one container. I also have an API back-end web server - another container.

I can run both containers individually with typical port forwarding, and access either from my host machine (Mac OS X) via the IP given by `docker-machine ip`. The issue is that the front-end is serving its static content correctly, but the javascript is making API requests to the wrong address. The front-end application needs to be configured with the address of the back-end *from the perspective of the host machine* since the host machine is the one actually executing the API calls.

Is there a way to pass the docker machine's IP address into the environment of the container? Or some other networking config that can make this happen.

Comment: "localhost" in my browser is my Mac. docker-machine is a linux VM on some other address. The containers are then running within that VM, with ports forwarded out to the VM, but not to the Mac. Here's the doc page about it: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/

Comment: You can set port-forward between the MAC and the VM by docker-machine through SSH for example.

Comment: IMO it would be best if you set up your nginx to act as a reverse proxy to whatever backend you are using. That way, your API URLs can stay relative to the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

More of a work-around than an actual answer:

I was able to modify the front-end config to use "document.location.hostname" in place of a statically-defined address.

The option considered was to have an entry in /etc/hosts that dynamically updates based on some script (see below) so that the VM is always referenceable by some static name, and then configure the front-end to use that name. This is more of a hack, but could apply in more general circumstances.

```
if [ ! -z "$DOCKER_HOST" ]; then
    ip=`echo $DOCKER_HOST | grep -o '\d\+\.\d\+\.\d\+\.\d\+'`
    grep -v "$ip" /etc/hosts | grep -v "docker-dev" > tmp_hosts
    echo "$ip docker-dev" >> tmp_hosts
    sudo mv tmp_hosts /etc/hosts
fi
```